# Why isn't there a receiver for this method?

Tags: ruby

Hi I'm currently looking at a ruby quiz solution (http://rubyquiz.com/quiz76.html) and it makes sense to me, but I am having trouble understanding why there isn't a `self` or any type of receiver for the methods `shift, pop, scramble` in `munge_word`:

```
class Array
  def munge_each
    map { |word| word.split(//).munge_word }
  end

  def munge_word
    first, last, middle = shift, pop, scramble
    "#{first}#{middle}#{last}"
  end

  def scramble
    sort_by{rand}
  end
end
```

Is it because it opened up the Array class and added functions to it? Are those methods class methods? I thought that syntax of `var1, var2 = var3, var4` was just for concise multiple assignment of variables. I've never seen it done with methods on one side. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
first, last, middle = shift, pop, scramble
```

This is essentially equivalent to

```
first = shift
last = pop
middle = scramble
```

The receiver (for `shift`, `pop` and `scramble` methods) is implicit and it is `self`. Which is an instance of `Array`, because `munge_word` is an instance method.

> I've never seen it done with methods on one side.

Variables, methods - it doesn't matter. Right-hand values just need to be a list (or array) of expressions. Any expressions. Look:

```
x = 1

a, b = (x * 2), (x / 0 rescue 5)

a # => 2
b # => 5
```

Comment: It's important to note that in the assignments like `first = shift`, only the right-hand side of the equals sign will be interpreted as a message to self. Assignments without a receiver are always simple variable assignments, so this will not call any `first=` method your class might happen to have.

Comment: @Chuck: Yes, it's important, thanks. Got bitten by it a couple of times in the early days :)

Answer (score 2):

self is always optional as the receiver for an instance method. To put it another way, a bare instance method call is always taken as being directed to self.

So, since parentheses are also optional, `shift` is a method call and is taken to mean `self.shift`. Since `self` is an array (because these are instance methods defined where the Array class has been opened up), we are telling some array to shift. And so on.